# How to uninstall chef-client and the whole Chef package

Tags: uninstallation, chef-infra

Is uninstalling Chef-Client just as easy as removing the directory, and making sure its not in the rc files? Is there a way to use knife to uninstall chef-client?

--2013-06-26_EDIT--

Updating this question to say, how to remove chef and all its other pieces from OS X, and Linux after using 1.) The Omnibus installer, and 2.) A bootstrapped node? Since I was trying to use Chef on my Mac, and had RVM installed, chef would not work, so now, I need to figure out how to remove chef.

--2015-03-08 EDIT --
Seems Opscode has put out their own instructions for uninstalling ChefDK. As far as the agent goes, it'd be the same method, using the package manager, or Add/Remove Programs.
http://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html#uninstall

Comment: It depends on OS and how you installed chef.

Comment: RHEL 5,6 and CentOS 6.4 for my personal at home project. I used the omnibus installer to install chef, and had to remove RVM Rubies from those OS's because of conflicts I was having.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To help answer my own question, I found that depending on how you install Chef, depends on how you uninstall it. You can do the:

Redhat/CentOS

```
rpm -qa *chef*
yum remove <package>
```

Or if you installed it with ruby gems:

```
gem uninstall chef-<version>
```

However, for using an Omnibus installer, there wasn't an RPM package, and on my Mac OSX 10.6.8, I couldn't find anything about it. So, I realized that chef is self-contained, so I just deleted the directory in the `/opt/` directory. Once I did that, I was able to use my RVM Ruby's.

--2015-03-08--
Opscode provides their own instructions for uninstalling ChefDK, and the Agent.
http://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html#uninstall

Comment: Did some debugging on Mac OS X Mavericks and the `install.sh` "Omnibus installer" creates a temp directory containing `chef--mac_os_x-10.7-x86_64.sh` (10.7 atm) that creates another temp directory containing `makeselfinst` that has `DEST_DIR=/opt/chef` in it. So that's true, deleting `/opt/chef` removes it but there will be some symlinks in `/usr/bin` pointing to nowhere you might also want to remove: `chef-client, chef-solo, chef-apply, chef-shell, knife, shef & ohai`. hth

Comment: I also use the above command but also do the following (on CentOS): `rm -rf /var/chef; rm -rf /etc/chef; rm -rf /opt/chef` and then knife node delete NODE_NAME followed by knife client delete NODE_NAME.  Now the node should be ready for re-installing Chef if necessary.

Answer (score 11):

If you're on debian/ubuntu (or a system with dpkg) just check the status of the package:

```
dpkg --list | grep chef # or dpkg --status chef
```

then purge (see man dpkg):

```
dpkg -P chef
```

Comment: I'm not near my computer, but would the same, `rpm -qa | grep *chef*` work, and allow me to see what I needed to remove? I didn't think about that until just now.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this when trying to figure out how to remove chef from a cloud server (Ubuntu in this case). I used chef to configure a machine, but I want to bake an image and not have chef on it.  So for those looking for similar

To remove chef-client that was installed in *omnibus* fashion:

- `sudo rm -rf /opt/chef` (This is where most of it is)
- `sudo rm -rf /etc/chef` (Hints and the like for the chef-client)
- `for P in /usr/bin/chef-*; do [ -e "$P" ] && sudo rm -f "$P"; done` (links for chef commands)
- `sudo rm -f /usr/bin/knife /usr/bin/ohai /usr/bin/chef` (other links to chef commands)

Comment: Use rpm / apt-get to remove chef / omnibus packages. If you just delete files an next chef bootstrap or initial run will fail since will find rpms/debs installed.

Comment: @2mia I used `dpkg -P chef` from an answer of this question, and still this issue helped me to remove other files. I still had the `/etc/chef`, `/usr/bin/chef-*` and `/usr/bin/knife /usr/bin/ohai /usr/bin/chef` files on my node. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Execute the below series of commands as a root user:

**On Ubuntu/Debian:**

```
dpkg -P chef;
rm -rf /opt/chef /var/chef /etc/chef;
for P in /usr/bin/chef-*; do [ -e "$P" ] && sudo rm -f "$P"; done;
rm -rf /usr/bin/knife /usr/bin/ohai /usr/bin/chef;
```

This is also a solution for the error below that occurs during the bootstrap process on Ubuntu [because of the presence of old version of chef-client]

ERROR: Cannot find a resource for apt_update on ubuntu version 14.04

**On RHEL/CentOS:**

```
rm -rf /opt/chef; rm -rf /etc/chef; 
for P in /usr/bin/chef-*; do [ -e "$P" ] && sudo rm -f "$P"; done
rpm -qa | grep chef-server | xargs yum erase -y;
userdel -f chef_server; userdel -f opscode-pgsql; 
rm -rf /usr/bin/knife /usr/bin/ohai /usr/bin/chef /opt/chef-server/ /var/chef/ /var/opt/chef-server/ /var/log/chef-server/ /etc/chef /etc/chef-server/ /etc/chef /etc/chef-server/;
```